# Including % with decodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript, uri

I am creating some random strings with % as a symbol and some URI components (ex. %27), but I am unable to add % with characters following it. ex. %27. I am using the decodeURIComponent() because of some characters like ' (%27), " (%22).

```
//'Hello'
decodeURIComponent('%27Hello%27');

//No Output
decodeURIComponent('%Hello%');
```

Any idea on how to include % in a string and use decodeURIComponent.

Answer (score 0):

`decodeURIComponent` is meant to decode the output of `encodeURIComponent`, which would never produce `'%Hello%'`. You probably don't need to call `decodeURIComponent` at all.